# Referenicng a single user on an active directoy group inside People or group colum

Tags: 2013, permissions, active-directory, groups, people-picker

I am working on a team site inside SharePoint web application 2013, and I have defined the following on my sub-site permission:

1. Inside a "Service Desk Member" group I defined it to have an Active directory group, as follows:

[image]

2. Then I defined a site column of type "People or group" and I defined it to reference the above SharePoint group :

[image]

3. Currently when I want to reference a user (either inside a People Picker or by auto completing the user name), I cannot see the users that are inside the AD group, instead I can select the group itself. I though that I can start typing a username and get all the users defined inside the group, or the people picker would show the users that are inside the AD group not the group itself.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People pickers will not enumerate AD groups.

A work around is to create a group of individuals. You do not need to give this group permission to the site, but all the members need to be included to be surfaced in the people picker.

Comment: but even the autocomplete column will not be able to show users inside the AD group ... for example when i am showing the people or group site column inside a default create or edit form ,, and i try to auto complete a user inside the AD group it will not be shown,, not sure how to fix this ?

Comment: you can't afaik, it will not enumerate the membership of an AD group, you have to list them out individually.